# PHP Array Removing Matching Values

Tags: php

I built this function in PHP so far called removeAllValuesMatching, but I cannot seem to get it working. I am passing in two parameters $arr and $value. Not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
$arr = array(
   'a' => "one",
   'b' => "two",
   'c' => "three",
   'd' => "two",
   'e' => "four",
   'f' => "five",
   'g' => "three",
   'h' => "two"
);
function removeAllValuesMatching($arr, $value){
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
 if ($arr[$key] == $value){
 unset($arr[$key]);
 }
 }
 return $arr = array_values($arr);
 }

print_r(removeAllValuesMatching($arr, "two"));

?>
```

Comment: What isn't working? "I am passing in two parameters $arr and $value. Not sure why this is happening." - are you missing something between these two sentences?

Comment: When I pass in the parameter of ($arr, "two"), It prints out none of the elements of the array. It should print out to the screen one, three, four, five, three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting `$value` here:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
```

Simply rename it:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == $value) {
```

---

However, a better way to delete elements from an array is this:

```
function removeAllValuesMatching(array $arr, $value) {
    $keys = array_keys($arr, $value);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my full version, with no variables collision and indenting : that's not an option, you should always indent correctly

```
<?php 
$arr = array(
    'a' => "one",
    'b' => "two",
    'c' => "three",
    'd' => "two",
    'e' => "four",
    'f' => "five",
    'g' => "three",
    'h' => "two"
);

function removeAllValuesMatching($arr, $arg){
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
        if ($arr[$key] == $arg){
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $arr = array_values($arr);
}

print_r(removeAllValuesMatching($arr, "two"));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix for your method, but [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) will acheive the same result, while also allowing you to remove multiple values.

```php
$arr = [
   'a' => "one",
   'b' => "two",
   'c' => "two",
   'd' => "three",
];  
$filtered = array_diff($arr, ['one', 'two']);
print_r($filtered); // Array([d] => three)
```

Comment: And, of course, you could update the original array without an intermediary array: `$arr = array_diff($arr, ['one', 'two']);`